# How can I connect a Fona to an Adafruit feather?

Tags: serial, pins, hardware, wires

I have this adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266/pinouts

and I want to connect a Fona board. But I am not certain which pins have the aforementioned software serial pins
necessary to make the required connections.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

from the Fona tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-3g-cellular-gps-breakout/arduino-wiring

which pins on the adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266 should I use for pin:
"TX connects to digital 3 (9 on Leo/Micro, 10 on Mega) "

where the feather doesn't have this a pin3.
similarly, which pins correspond to RST and RX?

Comment: you want RX-TX, TX to RX, reset to whatever you have free.

Comment: I'll try it, although in the tutorials it is not configured that way

Comment: if you need softwareserial, as opposed to hw, on the ESP pins 4+5 are going to be your best bet. if you don't need SPI, 13+15 will work as well.